# Alternate Wifi drivers in Debian; will be lost with kernel update?

Tags: debian, wifi

Linux debian 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1 (2017-05-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux (Debian Stretch)

I am using the rtl8821ae non-free drivers from Debian; there's frequent insatiability (power safe is off / wifi save disabled in tlp), so I was considering using the lwfinger repo ( https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/master/rtl8821ae ) for alternate drivers.

My question:
If lwfinger's drivers end up working better than the non-free from Debian, what happens if a kernel update is ran?  Will I lose the wifi and have to recompile the driver?

Is there a way to install this driver first and then disable the non-free drivers? (I don't have access to Ethernet)

Answer (score 1):

> Will I lose the wifi and have to recompile the driver?

Yes

You should recompile the driver because the module should be on the following path:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms//rtl8821ae .ko
```

On the Old kernel `4.9.0-2`:

```
/lib/modules/4.9.0-2-amd64/updates/dkms//rtl8821ae .ko
```

On the newest kerenl `4.9.0-3` :

```
/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/updates/dkms//rtl8821ae .ko
```

Comment: Appreciate the insight.  What's the best way to install the alternate driver without ethernet access?  I've only installed packages from the Debian repos before, so I'm unsure how to go about getting it going.

Comment: Actually, if you install it correctly, dkms will take care of recompiling it for you, automatically.

Comment: @necrom The easiest way to copy it over (if you don't have network access) is probably a USB flash stick.

Comment: You have already download the source from the git repo , just build it

Comment: I have the source unzipped, I `cd rtlwifi_new` then `make` and get: `make -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/build M=/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/build'
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2` the **build** directory is empty.  Not sure what to do to finish the install?